# Unsatisfied linker error when linking with openssl libraries built for Android

Tags: ssl, android-ndk, openssl

Am  getting the following error when linking with openssl libs (ssl/crypto) with my Android native code. I used openssl v1.0.2l code and built it using ndk-build available under android-sdk/ndk-bundle directory.

**Error Info**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.pkg-name.client, PID: 26925
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: **dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "i2d_DHxparams"** referenced by "/data/app/com.pkg-name.client-1/lib/arm/libnative-lib.so"...
```

My android-config.make file has the following:

```
#
# These flags represent the build-time configuration of openssl for android
#
# They were pruned from the "Makefile" generated by running ./Configure from import_openssl.sh
#

# From CLFAG=   
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DL_ENDIAN -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall #-DTERMIO

# From DEPFLAG=
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DOPENSSL_NO_EC_NISTP_64_GCC_128 -DOPENSSL_NO_SCTP \
                -DOPENSSL_NO_CAMELLIA -DOPENSSL_NO_CAPIENG -DOPENSSL_NO_CAST -DOPENSSL_NO_CMS -DOPENSSL_NO_GMP -DOPENSSL_NO_IDEA -DOPENSSL_NO_JPAKE -DOPENSSL_NO_MD2 -DOPENSSL_NO_MDC2 -DOPENSSL_NO_RC5 -DOPENSSL_NO_SHA0 -DOPENSSL_NO_RFC3779 -DOPENSSL_NO_SEED -DOPENSSL_NO_STORE -DOPENSSL_NO_WHIRLPOOL

#Copied by seaching for the OPENSSL_NO_
#LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DOPENSSL_NO_DEPRECATED

# Extra
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DOPENSSL_NO_HW -DOPENSSL_NO_ENGINE -DZLIB

# Debug
# LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DCIPHER_DEBUG
```

Please let me know if I need to enable any flag.
I tried the pre-built openssl library for Android and getting similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.pkg-name.client, PID: 26925
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: **dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "i2d_DHxparams"**
> referenced by "/data/app/com.pkg-name.client-1/lib/arm/libnative-lib.so"...
> ```

`i2d_DHxparams` is a macro in OpenSSL 1.1.0, not 1.0.2:

```
$ cd openssl
$ grep -IR i2d_DHxparams
crypto.map:        i2d_DHxparams;
util/libcrypto.num:i2d_DHxparams                           2206 1_1_0   EXIST::FUNCTION:DH
doc/man3/d2i_X509.pod:i2d_DHxparams,
include/openssl/dh.h:# define i2d_DHxparams_fp(fp,x) \
include/openssl/dh.h:    ASN1_i2d_fp(i2d_DHxparams,(fp), (unsigned char *)(x))
include/openssl/dh.h:# define i2d_DHxparams_bio(bp,x) \
include/openssl/dh.h:    ASN1_i2d_bio_of_const(DH, i2d_DHxparams, bp, x)
include/openssl/dh.h:int i2d_DHxparams(const DH *a, unsigned char **pp);
crypto/dh/dh_ameth.c:        return i2d_DHxparams(a, pp);
crypto/dh/dh_asn1.c:int i2d_DHxparams(const DH *dh, unsigned char **pp)
apps/dhparam.c:                i = i2d_DHxparams_bio(out, dh);
```

It sounds like you might be using the wrong headers or library. Perhaps you have 1.1.0 headers on-path and they are being picked up before the Android headers.

---

***EDIT***: It looks like the symbol is present in OpenSSL 1.0.2, too:

```
$ git checkout OpenSSL_1_0_2-stable
$ grep -IR i2d_DHxparams
crypto.map:        i2d_DHxparams;
util/libeay.num:i2d_DHxparams                           4683    EXIST::FUNCTION:DH
crypto/dh/dh.h:# define i2d_DHxparams_fp(fp,x) \
crypto/dh/dh.h:    ASN1_i2d_fp(i2d_DHxparams,(fp), (unsigned char *)(x))
crypto/dh/dh.h:# define i2d_DHxparams_bio(bp,x) \
crypto/dh/dh.h:    ASN1_i2d_bio_of_const(DH, i2d_DHxparams, bp, x)
crypto/dh/dh.h:int i2d_DHxparams(const DH *a, unsigned char **pp);
crypto/dh/dh_ameth.c:        return i2d_DHxparams(a, pp);
crypto/dh/dh_asn1.c:int i2d_DHxparams(const DH *dh, unsigned char **pp)
apps/dhparam.c:                i = i2d_DHxparams_bio(out, dh);
```

But it does not appear to be present in 1.0.1:

```
$ grep -IR i2d_DHxparams
crypto.map:        i2d_DHxparams;
```

Comment: @user3391612 - I checked out the 1.0.2 branch, and the symbol it there also. I'm not sure what to make of it. Find OpenSSL's `libcrypto.so` and run `strings` on it to dump the OpenSSL version. I.e., `strings libcrypto.so | egrep -i 'OpenSSL|version'`. It really sounds like the headers and library do not match. Let's ping Matt Caswell, who is one of the OpenSSL devs.

Comment: I have used openssl v1.0.2l headers in my code.

opensslv.h has the following macro defined.
# define OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER  0x100020cfL

I hit another linkerr problem with another device.

09-28 13:23:52.905 29981-29981/com.pkg-name.client E/art: dlopen("/data/app/com.pkg-name.client/lib/arm/libnative-lib.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "EC_curve_nist2nid" referenced by "libnative-lib.so"...

Comment: I ran strings command on libcryto.a and found the version as "part of OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017"

Comment: Answering the ping but not sure I can add much to the above discussion. The symbol is definitely present in 1.0.2 - but I'm not familiar with building on Android so I cannot suggest what the issue is here.

Comment: @MattCaswell - Do you know if Google is doing anything special with their port? Maybe converting some `#defines` into weak symbols?

Comment: You mean BoringSSL? Maybe - but I couldn't say. Not sure how that is relevant here though if we are explicitly linking with OpenSSL.